# How to show all available currency prices in magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3, currency, multicurrency, currency-rates

[image: Product price]

All the products in my project are configurable. I managed to convert price using below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product1 = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product1->getId() );
$price = $product->getFinalPrice();
$currencysymbol = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currency2 = $currencysymbol->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$currency = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency')->load($currency2);
echo $price;
echo $currency2;


if($currency2 == 'SAR'){

    echo $currency->convert($price,'AED');
}
elseif($currency2 == 'AED'){
    echo $currency->convert($price,'SAR');
}
```

But by default when product options are selected the product price varies dynamically for a configurable product. In this situation how to pass the different products id's on different options selected.